# How to stub a method having a parameter and raise exception using mocha?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mocking, minitest, stub

I am trying to stub an instance method of a class having a single parameter. Here is a simplified form of the class.

```
class GetPost
  def call(post_id)
    #some meaningful stuffs
  end
end

class GetPreviewTemplate
  def call(post_id)
    begin
      GetPost.new().call(post_id)
    rescue => e
      Post.find_by_ref(post_id).update(failed: true)
      raise
    end
  end
end
```

And here is how I am trying to stub `call` method of `GetPost` to raise an error so that I can verify failing scenario in `GetPreviewTemplateTest`.

```
test 'that should NOT get the HTML content of non-existing dummy post from CMS' do
  GetPost.any_instance.stubs(:call).with(any_parameters).raises(ArgumentError)

  GetPreviewTemplate.new(@post.id).call

  assert_not @post.status
end
```

I am getting following error while running the test

```
Wordpress::GetPreviewTemplateTest#test_that_should_NOT_get_the_HTML_content_of_non_existing_dummy_post_from_CMS:
ArgumentError: ArgumentError
    app/services/wordpress/get_preview_template.rb:19:in `call'
```

Suggestions, please.

Comment: What is your question? The `ArgumentError` is raised so the stub seems to be actually working!?

Comment: @BoraMa you catch it. Choosing `ArgumentError` was a wrong decision and I was fooled by that error assuming mocha is not able to stub method properly. Actually it was doing what is expected. Your question gave a hint, replaced `ArgumentError` with `StandardError` and voila, I started getting new error `StandardError`. After debugging a while I found that the exception is caught and been re-raised again so finally failed in the caller Test class.